Minifilter - Failure in Registration
I was developing a basic kernel-mode minifilter driver for x64 Windows 10. It compiled without any problem. But when I installed and ran it using sc start driver, the output I get in dbgview is this: SimpleMinifilter: FltRegisterFilter failed with status 0xc0000034 (which stands for STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND).
Below is the view of cmd:
C:\Windows\system32>sc start driver
[SC] StartService FAILED 2:

The system cannot find the file specified.

Below is the relevant code snippet:
#include <fltKernel.h>

// Declare global variables for the filter handle and callbacks
PFLT_FILTER gFilterHandle = NULL;

// Callback prototype for unload routine
NTSTATUS UnloadDriver(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags);

// Minifilter operation registration
const FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};

// Filter registration structure
const FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {
    sizeof(FLT_REGISTRATION),    // Size
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,    // Version
    0,                           // Flags
    NULL,                        // Context
    Callbacks,                   // Operation callbacks
    UnloadDriver,                // Unload routine
    NULL,                        // Instance setup
    NULL,                        // Instance query teardown
    NULL,                        // Instance teardown start
    NULL,                        // Instance teardown complete
    NULL,                        // Generate file name
    NULL,                        // Normalize name component
    NULL                         // Normalize context cleanup
};

// Unload routine - called when the driver is unloaded
NTSTATUS UnloadDriver(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags) {
    // Unregister the minifilter driver
    FltUnregisterFilter(gFilterHandle);
    DbgPrint("SimpleMinifilter: Unloaded\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

// Driver entry function - called when the driver is loaded
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    NTSTATUS status;

    // Register the minifilter driver with the filter manager
    status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &gFilterHandle);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DbgPrint("SimpleMinifilter: FltRegisterFilter failed with status 0x%x\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    // Start filtering I/O operations
    status = FltStartFiltering(gFilterHandle);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        FltUnregisterFilter(gFilterHandle);
        DbgPrint("SimpleMinifilter: FltStartFiltering failed with status 0x%x\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    DbgPrint("SimpleMinifilter: Loaded and filtering\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


I rechecked the code and the path to .sys many times. I am running this in test mode, so there is no issue with driver signature enforcement (which I have also confirmed by installing and running another driver i created and it runs without any problem). I have removed the .inf file as I do with my other drivers. I use sc create type= kernel binPath= "C:\\...\\driver.sys" to register my driver.

You need to have the registry entries set correctly. What does your inf look like?

Below is the inf:
Part 1:
;
; Driver.inf
;
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=FSFilterSystem
ClassGuid={5d1b9aaa-01e2-46af-849f-272b3f324c46}
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
DriverVer=09/01/2024,1.0.0.0
CatalogFile=Driver.cat
PnpLockdown=1
[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=ManufacturerSection
[ManufacturerSection]
%DeviceDesc%=InstallSection.NTx86,NTx86
%DeviceDesc%=InstallSection.NTamd64,NTamd64
[InstallSection.NTx86]
CopyFiles=DriverCopyFiles
[InstallSection.NTamd64]
CopyFiles=DriverCopyFiles
[DriverCopyFiles]
Driver.sys

Part 2:
[MiniFilter.Service]
LoadOrderGroup = "FSFilter System"
[MiniFilter]
Instance1.Altitude = "41235"
[SourceDisksNames]
1="Driver Disk",,,""
[SourceDisksFiles]
Driver.sys=1
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=13
[Strings]
ManufacturerName="Your Company" ; Replace with your company name
DeviceDesc="Register Filter Driver"
Although, I have removed the inf before compiling. Is inf necessary? If yes, is there anything missing from my inf?

You need the AddReg section as described here.

Below is my new inf:
; PreventFileAccess.inf
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=ActivityMonitor
ClassGuid={b86dff51-a31e-4bac-b3cf-e8cfe75c9fc2}
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
DriverVer = 10/16/2024,10.28.46.521
CatalogFile=PreventFileAccess.cat ; Catalog file for digital signature
PnpLockdown=1
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=12 ; System32\drivers directory
PreventFileAccess.DriverFiles = 12
[DefaultInstall.NTamd64]
CopyFiles=PreventFileAccess.DriverFiles
AddReg=PreventFileAccess.AddRegistry

Part 2:
[DefaultInstall.NTx86]
CopyFiles=PreventFileAccess.DriverFiles
AddReg=PreventFileAccess.AddRegistry
[DefaultInstall.Services]
AddService=PreventFileAccess,0x00000002,PreventFileAccess.Service
[SourceDisksFiles]
PreventFileAccess.sys=1
[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%,,,
[PreventFileAccess.DriverFiles]
PreventFileAccess.sys
[PreventFileAccess.Service]
DisplayName=%ServiceDisplayName%
ServiceType=0x00000002 ; SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType=0x00000003  ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl=0x00000001 ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL

Part 3:
ServiceBinary=%%SystemRoot%%\System32\drivers\PreventFileAccess.sys
LoadOrderGroup="FSFilter Activity Monitor"
AddReg=PreventFileAccess.AddRegistry
Dependencies   = FltMgr
[PreventFileAccess.AddRegistry]
HKLM,"System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System\PreventFileAccess","EventMessageFile",0x00020000,"%%SystemRoot%%\System32\drivers\PreventFileAccess.sys"
HKLM,"System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System\PreventFileAccess","TypesSupported",0x00010001,7
;HKR,"Parameters","SupportedFeatures",0x00010001,0x3

Part 4:
[Strings]
ManufacturerName="Your Company Name"
ServiceDisplayName="PreventFileAccess Driver"
DiskName="PreventFileAccess Driver Installation Disk"

It's very difficult to read this across multiple comments; just post the content in your question. You're missing the Instances registry entries which are required. At a minimum you need Instances|DefaultInstance=<whatever>, Instances\<whatever>|Altitude, and Instances\<whatever>|Flags.

I tend to avoid using .inf files, so as an alternative you can dynamically create these registry entries in your DriverEntry() prior to calling FltRegisterFilter().

I first did compile without using .inf file (I have mentioned it in the question itself) and made registry changes manually using regedit. Didn't work, same problem even then. I'll try Instances before coming back again.

Didn't work. I thought maybe my driver or something in .inf maybe a problem. So, I downloaded this: https://github.com/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/tree/main/filesys/miniFilter/minispy official example of Microsoft. Even this didn't run with same problem.
